# Android - Keep service alive even if app gets killed in Android 11

Tags: android, android-service, kill, foreground-service

A few years ago I researched about keeping a **NON** foreground service alive even if the app gets killed. I concluded that the best bet was a "hack" where you would do something like this:

```
void startServicesAliveChecker(){
    Intent postponeIntent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long t = c.getTimeInMillis()+3000;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 333,postponeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,t,15000,pendingIntent);
}
```

Basically have the AlarmManager fire every X seconds. AlarmManager will be fired even if the app has been killed. And then the BroadcastReceiver `AlarmReceiver` will handle the intent to check if the service is running or not.

Does this solution still work in newer versions of Android? Google has really limited what developers can do in terms of "hacks" and I don't have time to thoroughly test this in several Android versions. Any knowledge sharing will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Please also note that there will be even more restrictions on such services in Android 12.

Comment: Can't you use Battery Optimization - Off and a WorkManager? There you can run "as much as you need".